# How to do Cox regression if we have a variable which violates an assumption?

Tags: regression, cox-model, assumptions

Is there a better way than stratification to do Cox regression for two variables, one qualitative and other quantitative, the qualitative (and more important one) violates an assumption of Cox regression

Comment: Do you mean that it violates the proportional hazards assumption? You can look into Cox models with time-dependent (or time-varying) coefficients. For example see here: Heinzl, H., & Kaider, A. (1997). Gaining more flexibility in Cox proportional hazards regression models with cubic spline functions. Computer methods and programs in biomedicine, 54(3), 201-208